# Alternative to WHERE clause

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way to only `SELECT` rows with certain data in a column, without using `WHERE`?

e.g. If I had this:

```
SELECT * FROM Users
WHERE town = 'Townsville'
```

is there a way to implement the `WHERE` clause into the `SELECT` statement?

something like

```
SELECT *, town('Townsville') FROM Users
```

It's a bizarre question but it's one I've been asked by my peers

Comment: Ask them why they are asking this. Context is important.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, MikaelEriksson - Basically it's a little questionnaire about SQL at work, I've come across a question stating "Select all users from the users table that come from Townsville, without using a where clause" And, I didn't know that was possible! Maybe I'm approaching this the wrong way..?

Comment: Also just stating that this questionnaire is in no way linked to my employement status with the company! It's just a bit of fun

Answer (score 17):

Not sure if this is the kind of crazy thing you were looking for....

**Disclaimer**: I have absolutely no idea why you would want to use this.

```
SELECT * 
FROM Users AS u
INNER JOIN (SELECT 'Townsville' town) towns 
  ON towns.town = u.Town;
```

Answer (score 17):

#### Data

```
DECLARE @Example AS table
(
    UserName varchar(30) NULL,
    Town varchar(30) NULL
);

INSERT @Example
    (UserName, Town)
VALUES
    ('Aaron', 'Not Townsville'),
    ('Bob', 'Not Townsville'),
    ('Charles', 'Townsville'),
    ('Charles', 'Townsville'),
    ('Charles', 'Townsville'),
    ('Charles', 'Townsville'),
    ('Dan', 'Townsville'),
    ('Eric', 'Not Townsville');
```

#### Alternative solutions

```
SELECT E.UserName, E.Town
FROM @Example AS E
GROUP BY E.Town, E.UserName
HAVING E.Town = 'Townsville'

-- OR

SELECT E.UserName, 'Townsville' AS Town
FROM @Example AS E
GROUP BY E.UserName
HAVING 1 = MAX(CASE WHEN E.Town = 'Townsville' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END);

-- OR

SELECT E.UserName, E.Town
FROM @Example AS E
INTERSECT
SELECT E.UserName, 'Townsville' AS Town
FROM @Example AS E
```

#### Retaining duplicates

```
-- :)
SELECT E.UserName, E.Town
FROM @Example AS E
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(NEWID())) AS CA (n)
GROUP BY E.Town, E.UserName, CA.n
HAVING E.Town = 'Townsville'

-- Simulating INTERSECT ALL
SELECT
    R.UserName,
    R.Town
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        E.UserName, 
        E.Town, 
        rn =
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                PARTITION BY E.UserName, E.Town 
                ORDER BY E.UserName, E.Town)
    FROM @Example AS E
    INTERSECT
    SELECT 
        E.UserName, 
        'Townsville', 
        rn = 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY E.UserName 
            ORDER BY E.UserName)
    FROM @Example AS E
) AS R;
```

Output:

```
╔══════════╦════════════╗
║ UserName ║    Town    ║
╠══════════╬════════════╣
║ Charles  ║ Townsville ║
║ Dan      ║ Townsville ║
╚══════════╩════════════╝
```

For the final example:

```
╔══════════╦════════════╗
║ UserName ║    Town    ║
╠══════════╬════════════╣
║ Charles  ║ Townsville ║
║ Charles  ║ Townsville ║
║ Charles  ║ Townsville ║
║ Charles  ║ Townsville ║
║ Dan      ║ Townsville ║
╚══════════╩════════════╝
```

Try it here: <kbd>[**Stack Exchange Data Explorer**](http://data.stackexchange.com/dba/revision/353420/456151/where-without-where)</kbd>

Comment: Very nice! I'm guessing I wouldn't be able to use this in a scenario where I don't have a column containing only unique data such as 'Username'? E.g. if I only had forename, surname, town.

Comment: @JoshStevenson Correct, though I added a suitably mad way to preserve duplicates as the final example, and then a sensible one.

Comment: For the `GROUP BY` solutions, you could also add the PK in the group by list (to be 100% sure that the queries return the same number of rows as the WHERE). Assuming of course that there is a PK ;)

Answer (score 15):

Another way.

```
SELECT U.*
FROM  dbo.Users U
CROSS APPLY (SELECT Town INTERSECT SELECT 'Townsville' ) CA;
```

([Repurposing Paul White's example data](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/be94c/1))

Answer (score 14):

"Just for fun" you can use an `order by` with `top(1) with ties`

```
select top(1) with ties *
from dbo.Users
order by case when town = 'Townsville' then 1 else 2 end;
```

This will order all rows with `Townsville` first since the case returns `1` if `town = 'Townsville'`. All other rows will have a `2` returned by the case.

The `with ties` clause makes the query return all rows that is a "tie" for the last place in the rows returned. Using `top(1)` in combination with `with ties` will then return all rows that has the same value as the first row in expression used in the order by clause.

Note, as Martin Smith pointed out in a comment, it will return **all rows** if you ask for a town that does not exist in the table.

If you don't fear the XML things of databases you could make use of a predicate in the nodes() function.

Borrowing the setup from Paul White.

```
select T.X.value('(UserName/text())[1]', 'varchar(30)') as UserName,
       T.X.value('(Town/text())[1]', 'varchar(30)') as Town
from (
     select *
     from @Example
     for xml path('row'), type 
     ) as C(X)
  cross apply C.X.nodes('/row[Town = "Townsville"]') as T(X);
```

Another version with `top` and `order by` that actually work when searching for not existing towns.

```
select top(
          select sum(case when town = 'Townsville' then 1 end)
          from @Example
          ) *
from @Example
order by case when town = 'Townsville' then 1 else 2 end
```

Answer (score 7):

You have two different things here.

```
SELECT * FROM Users
WHERE town = 'Townsville'
```

Will restrict the number of rows you get back to just those where town=`Townsville`

```
SELECT *, town('Townsville') FROM Users
```

Is going to pass the literal `Townsville` to a function called `town`.  It will not restrict the rows returned by the query and in fact if the function returns anything but a single value you will get an error.

There are other ways to restrict the number of rows you get back from a query.  The HAVING clause for example.  But it has several other requirements.

```
SELECT town FROM Users
GROUP BY town
HAVING town = 'Townsville'
```

Or an INNER JOIN although this one is a bit weird if you don't have a second table.

```
SELECT * FROM Users
INNER JOIN (SELECT 1 col1) UselessTable
    ON Users.town = 'Townsville'
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example using a common table expression (CTE).

```
with Town as 
(
    select 'Townsville' as Town
)
select *
  from Users u
  join Town  t on u.Town = t.Town
```

Answer (score 5):

Well you could do this:

```
    SELECT A.* 
    FROM Users A
         INNER JOIN Users B ON A.Id = B.Id AND B.town = 'Townsville'
```

Strictly speaking you're not using the WHERE clause

Answer (score 5):

Here is a <strike>idiotic</strike> entirely logical way to do it that I don't see yet....

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;  -- Our important work should be all the database cares about
GO
BEGIN TRANSACTION

DECLARE @MyTableVar table(<all columns in order from the user table>, oldtown VARCHAR(50));

UPDATE users
SET town = N'Townsville'
OUTPUT 
     inserted.*  -- We don't want to have to type out the columns because that would be too much work
    deleted.town
INTO @MyTableVar;

--Display the result set of the table variable to prevent undesirables from sullying our output by inserting incorrect data even though we should have exclusive access.
SELECT * -- Select everything we want except for the 'oldtown' column because that data was probably wrong anyway
FROM @MyTableVar;

UPDATE u -- We don't want to be bad stewards of our data
SET
    town = oldtown
FROM users u
    INNER JOIN @MyTableVar mtv ON mtv.town = u.town, <Match up all the columns to REALLY ensure we are matching the proper row>

COMMIT TRANSACTION -- Make sure we save our work
```

I can't imagine why this wasn't the first thing to be suggested.  :)

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT *, 
    case when town='Townsville' then 'Townsville' 
         else null 
    end as Town
FROM Users
```

All towns besides Townsville would be null. Problem solved.